# React Native shadow adds shadow to everything inside card

Tags: css, react-native

I am trying to generate a box shadow equivalent for React Native.

Here is my code:

```
<View style={{
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 5,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    elevation: 5,
}}
>
    <View styleName={"card promocard cardsize"} style={{
        marginBottom: this.state.promoBottom, marginRight: this.state.promoRight,
    }}>
        <View styleName="promo-name" style={{ backgroundColor: this.rand }}>
            <View styleName="promo-name-child">
                <Image style={{ borderRadius: 50, resizeMode: "contain", backgroundColor: "#FFF" }} styleName="promocard-logo-img" source={{ url: this.props.promo.merchant.logo }} />
                <Text style={{ color: "#fff" }} styleName="promo-name-text">{this.props.promo.merchant.name}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
        <View styleName="promo-inner-card">
            <Image styleName="promo-main-img" source={{ url: this.props.promo.photo }} />
            <View>
                <View styleName="promo-title">
                    <Text styleName="promo-title-text">{this.props.promo.title}</Text>
                </View>
                <View styleName="promo-desc">
                    <Text styleName="promo-desc-text">{this.props.promo.text}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

Rather than generate styles correctly around the rectangle (which is 330 by 175), it seems to apply the shadow to every element INSIDE the box.

I want something that looks like this:

https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/

I have been tearing my hair out, because every example I am seeing looks similar to the code I've got in my top level view, and yet I am getting shadows on all the text, and the images inside my view.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by adding a background color.

backgroundColor: "#FFF"